# How to give access to only specific group of user for login - django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms

I'm struggling with login for users from specific django group ,
unfortunately any group user is able to login without knowing whether he belongs to a group or not.

```
def loginstaff(request):
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    if request.method == "POST":
        fm= AuthenticationForm(request=request, data=request.POST)
        if fm.is_valid():
            uname= fm.cleaned_data['username']
            upass= fm.cleaned_data['password']
            User = authenticate(username=uname,password=upass)
            if User is not None:
                login(request,User)
                messages.success(request,'Logged in Successfully..!')
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/staffprofile/')
    else:
        fm=AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request,'loginstaff.html',{'form':fm})
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/staffprofile/')
```

I created only two groups.

help me with my code guys, but in brief:) bcz im just learning.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it this way,

supposed your group name (that you created) is " writer " for example:

```
def loginstaff(request):
  if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    # get all the users of the group writer
    users_in_group = Group.objects.get(name="writer").user_set.all()
    # only if that user is a part the group
    if request.method == "POST" and request.user in users_in_group :
    ... #the rest of your function here
```

hey thankyou so much it worked :),but I did little changes

```
def loginstaff(request):
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    users_in_group = Group.objects.get(name="STAFF").user_set.all()
    if request.method == "POST" :
        fm= AuthenticationForm(request=request, data=request.POST)
        if fm.is_valid():
            uname= fm.cleaned_data['username']
            upass= fm.cleaned_data['password']
            User = authenticate(username=uname,password=upass)
            if User is not None:
                **#I put this line here :)**
                if  User in users_in_group :
                    login(request,User)
                    messages.success(request,'Logged in Successfully..!')
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/staffprofile/')
```

again thankyou so much :)